# How to install MariaDB on Redhat Enterprise Linux?

Tags: yum, mariadb

I'm trying to install `MariaDB` on Red Hat Enterprise Linux in my AWS account.
It's failing below when I do a `sudo yum -y install mariadb-server`. How can I get the `libsystemd` library that it requires?

```
$ sudo yum -y install mariadb-server
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
2 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.1.13-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-daemon.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_DAEMON_31)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-common for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: galera for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-client for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-daemon.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libjemalloc.so.1()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.1.13-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package MariaDB-common.x86_64 0:10.1.13-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.1.13-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-daemon.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_DAEMON_31)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-daemon.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package galera.x86_64 0:25.3.15-1.rhel7.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libboost_program_options.so.1.53.0()(64bit) for package: galera-25.3.15-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package jemalloc.x86_64 0:3.3.1-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.1.13-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-daemon.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_DAEMON_31)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsystemd-daemon.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package boost-program-options.x86_64 0:1.53.0-14.21.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsystemd-daemon.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: libsystemd-daemon.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_DAEMON_31)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2):

The packages you are trying to install are for Red Hat Enterprise Linux / CentOS.

However, you are not running this operating system. Your instance is running Amazon Linux. Amazon Linux is not compatible with packages intended for RHEL/CentOS.

To resolve the problem, create a new instance running the latest version of RHEL or CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that solution install completed with CentOS 5 for repository on Amazonlinux. Read note backup [here](https://github.com/LempStacker/DatabaseRelated/blob/master/MariaDB/Backup/LearningNotesBackup/2015.10.20_%E5%9C%A8AWS%20EC2%E4%B8%ADYUM%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%9DMariaDB%E5%A0%B1%E9%8C%AF%E5%8F%8A%E5%8E%9F%E5%9B%A0.md)

MariaDB repository config at /etc/yum.conf.d/MariaDB.repo

```
[mariadb]
  name = MariaDB
  baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.1/centos6-amd64
  gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
  gpgcheck=1
```