# How to install mariadb on amazon linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, repository, mariadb

I referred to the link https://blog.adminfactory.net/mariadb-and-galera-on-aws-amazon-linux.html to install the mariadb on my amazon linux, since I did not find any other resource related to amazon linux. This instructs to add maria.repo.

When I visit the suggested [URL](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=Fibergrid&distro=CentOS&distro_release=centos7-amd64--centos7&version=10.1) I did not find anything related to amazon linux. I tried using centos 7. It threw up error. Is there any mariadb repo for amazon linux.

The error is

> Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
>              Requires: libsystemd-daemon.so.0()(64bit)
>   Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.1.13-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
>              Requires: libsystemd-daemon.so.0(LIBSYSTEMD_DAEMON_31)(64bit)
>    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Is it ok if I continue and install libsystemd-daemon.so

I just found another question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/768355/how-to-install-mariadb-on-redhat-enterprise-linux) the advice is to use linux OS. No solution on how to install Mariadb on amazon linux.

Comment: Why do you want to use Amazon Linux? Just use CentOS if you want an RHEL-based distro. You will have a **much** better time.

Comment: I am already using amazon linux. any solution for that.

Comment: You should not be using Amazon Linux. You've discovered one reason why this is the case. There are many, many more.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will go with Ubuntu. It would be appredciable if someone could find a way to work on amazon linux.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to install the MariaDB 5.5 CentOS repository list (created 2016-05-09 04:06 UTC).

Create the following file:

```
sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/maria.repo
```

Add the following contents to the file and save:

```
[mariadb]
name = MariaDB
baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/5.5/centos6-amd64
gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
gpgcheck=1
```

Then run the following commands:

```
sudo yum install -y MariaDB-server MariaDB-client
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

You should be all set. Run `mysql -u root` to log in.

You can secure MariaDB with the following command:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

More information: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysql_secure_installation/

Fortunately, I was trying to install MariaDB on Amazon Linux, myself. Just now I got it to work as above.

Comment: This version is now outdated and cause a lot of bugs, you can find latest on te website : https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories

Comment: Perfect! I replaced the baseurl with the most recent stable version for centos6 based on the link FAjir provided:
http://yum.mariadb.org/10.3/centos6-amd64

The centos7 ones look like they're not compatible with AWS linux

Answer (score 2):

Currently in Amazon Linux 2 you can install it with yum:

```
yum install mariadb
```

or

```
yum install mariadb-server
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same solution as I ran into the same problem and it really boils down to transparency from Amazon. I found that my server is based on epel 6 not epel 7 (which is what I use elsewhere). Check what epel version your server is using:

`sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo`

Within the repo file you should should see a few lines with `Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6`.

Since the repo is using Enterprise Linux 6 I need to use repos based on CentOS 6. If you have a different Linux version, ie 7, you will need to use a different version. Make sure you go to the below link and get the correct version for your server.

`https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories`